# Get Input from ion-input in Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I don't know how I can get input from ion-input and `console.log` it out. Every time I did it, it always outputted as `undefined`in the console. Is there a better way to do it? I'm a complete newbie to the Ionic Framework and Angular.

Here is my code :

```
src/pages/addtask/addtask.html
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar primary>
    <ion-title>
      Add Task
    </ion-title>

  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

  <ion-list>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating> Task </ion-label>
      <!-- Get Input from below -->
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="task" id="task"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Priority</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="priority" id="pri">
        <ion-option value="High">High</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="Normal">Normal</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="Low">Low</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>

    <div padding>
      <button ion-button color="greed" full round (click)="post()">Save</button>
    </div>


  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

```
src/pages/addtask/addtask.ts
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, IonicPage, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage'


@Component({
  selector: 'page-task',
  templateUrl: 'addtask.html'
})

export class AddTask {

  // post() outputs undefined undefined in the console

  post(){
    let tasksValue = (document.getElementById('task') as HTMLInputElement).value;
    let priVal = (document.getElementById('pri') as HTMLInputElement).value;
    console.log(tasksValue, priVal);
  }

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private storage: Storage) {

  }

  close(){
    this.navCtrl.pop()
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You firstly know how to handle Ionic forms.There are 3 ways of handling it.

1. Forms with `[(ngModel)]`
2. Forms with `FormBuilder`
3. Forms with `Templates`

Please read this [**official doc**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/forms/) for learning it deeply.

On your example above you have not followed any one of above methods.That was the reason where it doesn't work.

Comment: in this case, what would you recommend that I use to get the input?

Comment: I would like to recommend the `Forms with FormBuilder` method.That method is also called reactive forms method.But you can use `Forms with [(ngModel)]` method too.It is some what old AngularJS kind of method.

Comment: If you have any issues about those methods please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

TS

```
.....

export class AddTask {

 //first declare variable for your input.
task:any;
pri:any;

post(){
   console.log('task',this.task);
   console.log('pri',this.pri)
   } 
 }
```

HTML

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-label floating> Task </ion-label> 
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="task"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Priority</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="pri">
        <ion-option value="High">High</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="Normal">Normal</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="Low">Low</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>

    <div padding>
      <button ion-button  full (click)="post()">Save</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution :)